# Using fct_collapse on a subset of data

Tags: r, forcats

I am attempting to build a prediction model. One of my features are identifiers for U.S. States and Territories. The original list has 62 unique values, and I was able to reduce those down to 5 values using fct_collapse.

```
dat <- tibble(state = c('AA', 'AE', 'AK', 'AL', 'AP', 'AR', 'AS', 'AZ',
                        'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DC', 'DE', 'FL', 'FM', 'GA',
                        'GU', 'HI', 'IA', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'KS', 'KY',
                        'LA', 'MA', 'MD', 'ME', 'MH', 'MI', 'MN', 'MO', 
                        'MS', 'MT', 'NC', 'ND', 'NE', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM',
                        'None', 'NV', 'NY', 'OH', 'OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'PR',
                        'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 
                        'UNITED STATES MINOR OUTLYING ISLANDS', 'UT',
                        'VA', 'VI', 'VT', 'WA', 'WI', 'WV', 'WY'))
dat$census_region <- fct_collapse(dat$state,
    northeast = c("CT","ME","MA","NH","RI","VT","NJ","NY","PA"),
    midwest = c("IL","IN","MI","OH","WI","IA","KS","MN","MO","NE","ND","SD"),
    south = c("DE","FL","GA","MD","NC","SC","VA","DC","WV","AL","KY","MS","TN",
         "AR","LA","OK","TX"),
    west = c("AZ","CO","ID","MT","NV","NM","UT","WY","AK","CA","HI","OR","WA"),
    other = c("AA","AE","AP","AS","FM","GU","MH","None","PR",
         "UNITED STATES MINOR OUTLYING ISLANDS","VI"))
```

tail(dat,10)

A tibble: 10 x 2

| state | census_region |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |
| TX | south |
| UNITED STATES MINOR OUTLYING ISLANDS | other |
| UT | west |
| VA | south |
| VI | other |
| VT | northeast |
| WA | west |
| WI | midwest |
| WV | south |
| WY | west |

I am now trying to validate the model, and the smaller dataset does not have all 62 unique state identifiers:

```
dat_2 <- tibble(state = c('ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'KS', 'KY',
                          'LA', 'MA', 'MD', 'ME', 'MH', 'MI', 'MN', 'MO', 
                          'MS', 'MT', 'NC', 'ND', 'NE', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM',
                          'None', 'NV', 'NY', 'OH', 'OK'))
```

Now, if I attempt to use fct_collapse on the smaller dataset:

```
dat_2$census_region <- fct_collapse(dat_2$state,
    northeast = c("CT","ME","MA","NH","RI","VT","NJ","NY","PA"),
    midwest = c("IL","IN","MI","OH","WI","IA","KS","MN","MO","NE","ND","SD"),
    south = c("DE","FL","GA","MD","NC","SC","VA","DC","WV","AL","KY","MS","TN",
        "AR","LA","OK","TX"),
    west = c("AZ","CO","ID","MT","NV","NM","UT","WY","AK","CA","HI","OR","WA"),
    other = c("AA","AE","AP","AS","FM","GU","MH","None","PR",
        "UNITED STATES MINOR OUTLYING ISLANDS","VI"))
```

I get this:

*Warning message:
Unknown levels in `f`: CT, RI, VT, PA, WI, IA, SD, DE, FL, GA, SC, VA, DC, WV, AL, TN, AR, TX, AZ, CO, UT, WY, AK, CA, HI, OR, WA, AA, AE, AP, AS, FM, GU, PR, UNITED STATES MINOR OUTLYING ISLANDS, VI*

I have done something similar by grouping the states and territories by Roman Numerals, as defined by the Office of Management and Budget. My goal is to reduce down from 62 dummy variables to something more manageable.

**THE QUESTION:** is there an option within the `forcats` package (more particularly fct_collapse) that will assign only those values that are found and skip the "Uknown levels"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider tackling this a different way and just do `dat_2 |> left_join(dat)` per below.

This grabs the `census_region` from dat that matches the `state` in your smaller sample and keeps it as a factor.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tibble(state = c('AA', 'AE', 'AK', 'AL', 'AP', 'AR', 'AS', 'AZ',
                        'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DC', 'DE', 'FL', 'FM', 'GA',
                        'GU', 'HI', 'IA', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'KS', 'KY',
                        'LA', 'MA', 'MD', 'ME', 'MH', 'MI', 'MN', 'MO', 
                        'MS', 'MT', 'NC', 'ND', 'NE', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM',
                        'None', 'NV', 'NY', 'OH', 'OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'PR',
                        'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 
                        'UNITED STATES MINOR OUTLYING ISLANDS', 'UT',
                        'VA', 'VI', 'VT', 'WA', 'WI', 'WV', 'WY'))

dat$census_region <- fct_collapse(dat$state,
                                  northeast = c("CT","ME","MA","NH","RI","VT","NJ","NY","PA"),
                                  midwest = c("IL","IN","MI","OH","WI","IA","KS","MN","MO","NE","ND","SD"),
                                  south = c("DE","FL","GA","MD","NC","SC","VA","DC","WV","AL","KY","MS","TN",
                                            "AR","LA","OK","TX"),
                                  west = c("AZ","CO","ID","MT","NV","NM","UT","WY","AK","CA","HI","OR","WA"),
                                  other = c("AA","AE","AP","AS","FM","GU","MH","None","PR",
                                            "UNITED STATES MINOR OUTLYING ISLANDS","VI"))

dat_2 <- tibble(state = c('ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'KS', 'KY',
                          'LA', 'MA', 'MD', 'ME', 'MH', 'MI', 'MN', 'MO', 
                          'MS', 'MT', 'NC', 'ND', 'NE', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM',
                          'None', 'NV', 'NY', 'OH', 'OK'))

dat_2 |> left_join(dat)
#> Joining, by = "state"
#> # A tibble: 26 × 2
#>    state census_region
#>    <chr> <fct>        
#>  1 ID    west         
#>  2 IL    midwest      
#>  3 IN    midwest      
#>  4 KS    midwest      
#>  5 KY    south        
#>  6 LA    south        
#>  7 MA    northeast    
#>  8 MD    south        
#>  9 ME    northeast    
#> 10 MH    other        
#> # … with 16 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I really appreciate the quick response. The join makes so much sense! smh! I am curious about the symbol you have used in the join, this is the first time seeing it. (The |> ). What is the name of it? Thanks again

Comment: `|>` is the native pipe in recent releases of base R. You could also use `%>%` which does essentially the same thing. Either means "then do this" and they pass the result of one line along to the next so it's not necessary to keep naming lots of objects which may only be needed temporarily.